# Excel VBA Query: Want to uncolour a range of cells on right click

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to uncolour a range of cells in a 2 x 10 range upon right clicking on a cell. My code currently is not working. Any assistance would be appreciated. I am very new to VBA

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I9:J359")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Cancel = True
    Target.Offset(10, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
  End If
End Sub
```

Or any advice to improve this function would also be appreciated

Comment: When you say it's "currently no working", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: im guessing you are selecting more than 1 cells when you say **2x10** ,  the line `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` will exit the sub if you select more than 1 cells

Comment: @Skin My intention is for the code to 'uncolour' the cells in a 2x10 cell block with the activated cell being in the top left corner.

Comment: So two columns by 10 rows?

Comment: @Skin from the point of activecell yes.

Comment: I have to assume you want the un-highlighting to happen to selected cells if they’re in the range you specified, right?

Comment: If that’s the case then after the intersect target line you’d want to be using `Selection.Cells.Count` and `Selection.Offset(….` as I believe `Target` will only ever be a single cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, does this do what you want?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I9:J359")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        
        Cancel = True
        Target.Worksheet.Range(Target.Address & ":" & Target.Offset(9, 1).Address).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works just as intended. Thank you so much for this!